# How can I generate tables in php based on MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I have made a page on my website that has a table with information that supposed to displayed whenever a new record is add on my MySQL database here is my code:

```
<?php
  while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryD))
        {   
 echo "<table width='800' border='0' align='center' style='margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; background-color: #FFFFFF;' border-radius: '5px;' cellspacing='0px' cellpadding='2px;'>";
   echo "<tbody>";
     echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Name" . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='193' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Type" . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='98' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Phone" . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='98' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Age" . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='148' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Gender" . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='160' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Natunality" . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";

     echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . $r["Name"] . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . $r["Type"] . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . $r["Phone"] . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . $r["Age"] . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . $r["Gender"] . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . $r["Natu"] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";?>
```

and here is my query:

```
$queryD = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users");
```

All the code above is working fine but, my problem here is I want to repeat the table whenever a new user registered on the database. I have multiple record on my database but this code is showing only one table and only the first record. I want to show all the records, each one in a separated table and displaying them by stack them on top of each other. So how can I do that? hope you understand my question. Thank you

Comment: while loop not closed in your code

Comment: It looks like this code already is capable of displaying every row in a separate table. It's  not really clear to me what you need then.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes it is capable of displaying every row in a separate table but, it is overwriting on the previous table and not adding a new table after it

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Written output doesn't just disappear unless there is some other code here (ob_clean or so), that you're not showing.

Comment: @GolezTrol You are right bro, I have missed a "}" for the while loop.. Solved it now thank you for replaying

Comment: @user1844933 already notified me but did not see his comment